# C# Função converter string em xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Gostaria de saber como converter um `string` com `XML` *inline* para um `XML` com `tags`, estou utilizando o `XmlDocument`, tenho o seguinte código:

```
var MihaString="<MeuXML Info01="teste 0121245" Info02="2020-01-14" Info03="2019-12-30"/>";
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(MihaString);
var result = xmlDocument.OuterXml;
```

Porem mesmo utilizando o OuterXml ele mantem a mesma estrutura do xml de entrada.

Resultado esperado seria algo assim:

```
<MeuXMLPai> 
 <MeuXML>
  <Info01> teste 0121245 </Info01>
  <Info02> 2020-01-14 </Info02>
  <Info03> 2019-12-30 </Info03>
 </MeuXML> 
</MeuXMLPai>
```

Comment: Não entendi a sua duvida?

Comment: <MeuXMLPai>
  <MeuXML>
    <Info01>
        teste 0121245
    </Info01>   
    <Info02>
        2020-01-14
    </Info02>
    <Info03>
        2019-12-30
    </Info03>
</MeuXMLPai>
</MeuXML>

Comment: Queria transformar nesse xml:<MeuXMLPai> <MeuXML> <Info01> teste 0121245 </Info01> <Info02> 2020-01-14 </Info02> <Info03> 2019-12-30 </Info03> </MeuXMLPai> </MeuXML>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente, precisa ser criado um outro `XmlDocument` e criar os atributos desse anterior para filhos do novo:

```
var MihaString = "<MeuXML Info01=\"teste 0121245\" 
                          Info02=\"2020-01-14\" Info03=\"2019-12-30\"/>";
XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
xmlDocument.LoadXml(MihaString);
           
// a partir daqui é um novo arquivo.
XmlDocument xmlResult = new XmlDocument();

var root = xmlResult.CreateElement("MeuXMLPai");
var items = xmlResult.CreateElement("MeuXML");

foreach(XmlAttribute xmlAttribute in xmlDocument.DocumentElement.Attributes)
{
    var item = xmlResult.CreateElement(xmlAttribute.Name);
    item.InnerText = xmlAttribute.Value;
    items.AppendChild(item);
}
root.AppendChild(items);
xmlResult.AppendChild(root);
Console.WriteLine(xmlResult.OuterXml);
```

<sub>Online exemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wcn1uh</sub>

Comment: Entendi, mas minha string é dinamica, eu não consigo saber qual vai ser meus elementos, como por exemplo posso receber um XML assim: "<MeuXMLPai>
  <MeuXML Info01="teste 0121245" Info02="2020-01-14" Info03="2019-12-30">
    <ItemA Codigo="89" Descripcion="Testando" />
    <ItemB Codigo="100" Informacao="Testando" />
    <ItemC Teste="Certo" Aviso="Não" Erro="Não" />
  </MeuXML>
</MeuXMLPai>"

Comment: @LuizLanza nós aqui ajudamos de acordo com o que está na pergunta, e agora esse comentário é outra duvida, se preferir abra outro questionamento, mas, acredito que esse já tenha solucionada a duvida inicial. Ou seja você postou um problema e ele foi resolvido.

Comment: Não atendeu. Vou editar a pergunta para ficar mais claro.

Comment: Não pode editar a pergunta @LuizLanza para satisfazer nova duvida!

Comment: Não é uma nova dúvida, oque você respondeu ai não atende por causa desses 2 itens: 

var root = xmlResult.CreateElement("MeuXMLPai");
var items = xmlResult.CreateElement("MeuXML");

ja editei a pergunta, para deixar claro que seria dinâmico isso.

Comment: Vou reafirmar a sua duvida inicial foi respondida de acordo com o que estava na pergunta, vou reverter e se quiser crie uma nova pergunta com um texto mais apropriado, afinal isso é regra aqui e nem você nem eu podemos fazer nada. Obrigado, se quiser assinalar como resposta fique a vontade se não tudo bem!

Comment: Vc fez esse tanto de comentário, pedindo para eu abrir outra pergunta só porque queria que eu assinalasse sua resposta? achei que queria me ajudar.

Comment: Virgilio Novic, ta ai a nova pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/458398/c-converter-string-din%c3%a2mica-em-xml-com-tag

Comment: @LuizLanza não foi eu que comecei com os comentários e outra, ajudar todos ajudam o problema é o outro lado da moeda vocês querem aprender com a ajuda? bom deixa pra lá já abriu outro questionamento isso é importante, agora não pode mudar a pergunta original porque você acha que agora não deu certo.